# Using RxJs Observables - why isn't the subscriber notified when data changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/Rfmcrn9Ef3ABiVGDEZSi?p=preview

In this simple example, i set up an observable and a subscriber.   When i push a new item ("Labrador Retriever") to the array, I expected the subscriber to be notified.. not the case..

What am I missing here??

```js
const dogBreeds = ['hound', 'dachshund', 'Pekingnese', 'Pug', 'Mastiff'];

setTimeout(() => {
  dogBreeds.push('Labrador Retriever'); 
}, 1000); 

  const dogBreedObservable = Rx.Observable.from(dogBreeds);

  const dogBreedSubscriber = dogBreedObservable
        .subscribe(
      onNext,
      function onError(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
      },
      function onCompleted() {
        console.log('no more breeds!');
      }
    );

  function onNext(breed) {
   console.log('breed: ' + breed);
   console.log(dogBreeds);
  }
```

Comment: @Vic That would not even change `dogBreeds`, let alone notify the observable that something changed. It would simply return a value which would never be used anywhere. It's a pointless operation.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović you are totally right... `BehaviorSubject` is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a stream of `dogBreeds` as it was when you still haven't added any values. Subsequetial changes to `dogBreeds` will not emit, because you've never told it to do so.

What you should do is create a Subject. Since you want a starting value, you might be interested in [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html). What you need to do is to emit a new value, so for your demo, you might do something like the following.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.dogBreeds = [...this.dogBreeds, 'new', 'breed']
  dogBreedObservable.next(this.dogBreeds)
}, 10)
```

However, if you just want to do it in a more RxJS-like-way, you should probably consider using operator such as [`scan`]
(http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) to keep accumulated values of all breeds on each new breed that you want to add.